# PHP add html tags white list for sanitize input

Tags: php, mysql, sanitize

I found [GUMP](https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP) class for sanitize and validation data input and it works like this :

```
# Note that filters and validators are separate rule sets and method calls. There is a good reason for this.

require "gump.class.php";

$gump = new GUMP();

$_POST = $gump->sanitize($_POST); // You don't have to sanitize, but it's safest to do so.

$gump->validation_rules(array(
    'title'      => 'required',
    'story'      => 'required'

));

$gump->filter_rules(array(
    'title'    => 'trim|sanitize_string',
    'story'    => 'trim|sanitize_string',
));

$validated_data = $gump->run($_POST);

if($validated_data === false) {
    echo $gump->get_readable_errors(true);
} else {
    print_r($validated_data); // validation successful
}
```

In action this works well  and sanitizes all input data. for `story` field in need to add html tags like `<p><img><table>` but this class sanitizes all `$_POST` and removes all html tags.

I can't find out how to add white list(`<p><img><table>`) for sanitize?! How can I add a white list for html tags?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix the usage of English and spelling errors.  It is great that you have discovered how to markdown the code.

Answer (score 0):

A [quick look at the class](https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP/blob/master/gump.class.php#L284) shows you can't do that.

Another solution would be using the builtin function [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).